# Extracting exception thrown by unsuccessful message-processors in FirstSuccessful routing message processor

Tags: java, exception, routes, mule

I am addressing a fail-safe scenario as below.

But in the recoveryflow I am not able to get the exception or exceptionPayload that occurred due to the failure of the subflow1 or subflow2.

Is there any way I can get the exception thrown by the unsuccessful message processors in the First-sucessful routing processor.

I have looked into the Mule `FirstSuccessful` class code. From the loop in it, I can see the exception is caught but not saved.

Is there a way I can extend and have my own first-successful which can provide me the exception as well?

```
<flow name="main_flow" >
    ....
    ....
    <first-successful>
        <flow-ref  name="subflow_1" />
        <flow-ref  name="recoveryFlow1" />
    </first-successful>
    ....
    ....
    <first-successful>
        <flow-ref  name="subflow_2" />
        <flow-ref  name="recoveryFlow2" />
    </first-successful>
    ....
    ....
</flow>

<sub-flow name="subflow_1">
    ....
    ....
    <out-bound call to web-service />
    ....
    ....
</sub-flow>

<sub-flow name="subflow_2">
    ....
    ....
    <out-bound call to web-service />
    ....
    ....
</sub-flow>

<sub-flow name="revoceryFlow1" >
    <process communication based on the exception thrown by previous unsuccessful sub-flow 1>
    <some more processing so that the remaining main flow is not impacted because of the failue of the subflow 1  >
</sub-flow>

<sub-flow name="revoceryFlow2" >
    <process communication based on the exception thrown by previous unsuccessful sub-flow 2>
    <some more processing so that the remaining main flow is not impacted because of the failue of the subflow 2 >
</sub-flow>
```

Please advise if I am going in wrong direction. Is there any better approach than mine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.
There is not straight solution from the Mule. 
I have overwriten the FirstSuccessful behaviour and added properties with the exception details. These properties are then accessed in the next message processors inside the first-successful.

```
catch (Exception ex)
        {
            event.getMessage().setProperty("prevError",  ex.getMessage()  , PropertyScope.INVOCATION);
            event.getMessage().setProperty("prevErrorClass",  ex.getClass()  , PropertyScope.INVOCATION);
            failed = true;
        }
```